# How can I rotate a rectangle using a matrix and get the modified rectangle?

Tags: c#, matrix, rotation

I have searched all the links for rectangle rotation, but nothing seems to apply to my problem. I have a RectangleF structure and wish to feed it into a rotation matrix. Then use resulting RectangleF to pass into some other function.

The reason for wanting to use a matrix is because I may also want to perform a translation, and then perhaps a scale afterwards and pass the resultant rectangle into some other function, e.g.

```
RectangleF original = new RectangleF(0,0, 100, 100);
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.Rotate(35.0f);
m.Translate(10, 20);

....   (what do I do here ?)

RectangleF modified = (How/where do I get the result?)

SomeOtherFunction(modified);
```

How can I achieve this ?

I don't want to draw this rectangle on a screen or anything else. I just need the values, but all examples I have read use the graphics class to do the transform and draw which is not what I want.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `System.Drawing.Rectangle` structure is always orthogonal and cannot have a rotation. You can only rotate its corner points.

Here is an example of doing this with a `Matrix`:

```
Matrix M = new Matrix();

// just a rectangle for testing..
Rectangle R = panel1.ClientRectangle;
R.Inflate(-33,-33);

// create an array of all corner points:
var p = new PointF[] {
    R.Location,
    new PointF(R.Right, R.Top),
    new PointF(R.Right, R.Bottom),
    new PointF(R.Left, R.Bottom) };

// rotate by 15° around the center point:
M.RotateAt(15, new PointF(R.X + R.Width / 2, R.Top + R.Height / 2));
M.TransformPoints(p);

// just a quick (and dirty!) test:
using (Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics())
{
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightBlue, R);
    g.DrawPolygon(Pens.DarkGoldenrod, p );
}
```

The trick is to create an array of `Point` or `PointF` containg all points you are interested in, here the four corners; the `Matrix` can then transform those points according to all sorts of things you asked for, **rotation** around a point being one of them. Others include **scaling**, **shearing** and **translating**..

The result, as expected:

[image]

If you need this repeatedly you will want to create function to convert Rectangle to Point[] and back.

**Note**, as pointed out above, that the latter is not really possible, as **`Rectangle` will always be orthogonal, i.e. cannot be rotated**, so you will have to go for the corner points. Or switch to the `Rect` class from the `System.Windows` namespace as Quergo shows in his post.

Answer (score 0):

Use Rect if you can/want use System.Windows namespace. Rect is also always orthogonal but you can apply a rotate transform to its corner points. It is same procedure as using System.Drawing namespace.

```
var rect = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
Point[] cornerPoints = { rect.TopLeft, rect.TopRight, rect.BottomRight, rect.BottomLeft };

var m = new Matrix();

//define rotation around rect center
m.RotateAt(45.0, rect.X + rect.Width / 2.0, rect.Y + rect.Height / 2.0);

//transform corner points
m.Transform(cornerPoints);
```

Comment: Still an orthogonal Rect:
`transformed = {-164.142,-15.858,200,200}`

Comment: transformed = {X, Y, Width, Height} gives you no information about orthogonality. Check the corner points TopLeft and BottomRight instead. Width and Height are not changed by a rotation.

Comment: The OP asked for the rotation of the corner points. The accepted answer of TaW is the right solution.
As I tested `original.Transform(m)` will change the width and height. It modifies orginal to `{-70.711,20,141.421,141.421}`. It will stay orthogonal to the coordinate sytem, with TopLeft.Y = TopRight.Y. I guess it's the surrounding rectangle of the transformed rectangle the OP expected.

Comment: You are right. Changed the code sample to transformation of corner points. This seems to do the work.